# Convert Integer into Datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a df that gives me Date in a integer form, and i want to convert it into Datetime so i can continue to manipulate it.

Basically i have this DF where i have a Column like this below

```
    DATE
18010101
18010101
18010101
18010101
18010101
... ... ... ... ... ...
20123124
20123124
20123124
20123124
20123124
```

the respective order in this dateset is (Year, month, day, hour)

i've already tried to do something like this

```
df["Year"] = df.DATE[0:2]
df["Month"] = df.DATE[2:4]~
```

but it converts it into a float and for the first line example, it becomes similar to this

```
DATE    Year
18010101    18010101.0
```

where it was supposed to be

Year = 2018 or 18

I would appreciate a lot the help of you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.str.extract` and a regex

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[18010101], [18010101], [18010101], [18010101], [18010101],
                   [20123124], [20123124], [20123124], [20123124], [20123124]],
                  columns=['DATE'])
df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']] = df['DATE'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})')
```

---

| DATE | year | month | day | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18010101 | 18 | 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 18010101 | 18 | 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 18010101 | 18 | 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 18010101 | 18 | 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 18010101 | 18 | 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 20123124 | 20 | 12 | 31 | 24 |
| 20123124 | 20 | 12 | 31 | 24 |
| 20123124 | 20 | 12 | 31 | 24 |
| 20123124 | 20 | 12 | 31 | 24 |
| 20123124 | 20 | 12 | 31 | 24 |

Comment: i Would have to type every date line for the data set for this to work right!?!?

It has to many, subjects i think this doesnt apply for this DF, but thanks a lot i will use it in another df. 

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, you tried to split an int like a string.
But you can first convert it into a string (by `.astype(str)`) and then split it. Check the lines below.

```
date_str = df.DATE.astype(str)
df["Year"] = date_str.str[0:2]
df["Month"] = date_str.str[2:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your hour stamps actually from 1 to 24?  Normal convention for 24-hour time is 0-23 where you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[18010100], [18010100], [18010100], [18010100], [18010100],
                   [20123123], [20123123], [20123123], [20123123], [20123123]],
                  columns=['DATE'])

pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%y%m%d%H')
```

Or simply take 1 from each number beforehand like so:

````
df = pd.DataFrame([[18010101], [18010101], [18010101], [18010101], [18010101],
                   [20123124], [20123124], [20123124], [20123124], [20123124]],
                  columns=['DATE'])
pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']-1, format='%y%m%d%H')```
````